# Filling a UIPageViewController with data from a server?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

The main feature I'm looking to accomplish is that a user swipes left/right and the next pages slides in from the side and both screens are semi-showing until the swipe to the next page is complete. I've seen this functionality in page view controllers, but I'm not sure that's the direction to go.

I haven't found much on creating view controllers dynamically from server data from like a Firebase and I hardly have any experience using page view controllers, but if I'm simply looking for a scroll left/right is this the way to go?

If I had 300 pages I was going to have to potentially have a user swipe through, wouldn't it be awful to have the user have to download 300 pictures first?

More or less just looking for guidance before committing to an attempt as I'm still not sure I'm clear on where to begin.

Comment: If you got this to work, could you share an example?  I'm also trying to get this to work with a UIPageViewController and I am not getting the results I expected.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PageViewController that could be achieved. Follow this :

1. Design a screen (Xib or using Storyboard) by draggging UIPageViewController
2. Set its delegate and implement delegate methods
3. Important step is to configure how many pages you want during transition
4. viewControllerAfterViewController and viewControllerBeforeViewController these two methods needs to configure since it loads **Previous** and **Next** Screen.

Now wherever you need just subclass : This viewcontroller and load this xib accordingly .

Here is few code sample :

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < characterImages.count {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerBeforeViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    if itemIndex < characterImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = characterImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
}
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think page view is definitely what I'm looking to use, you're right. 

In terms of downloading the images from firebase though...in a tableview if I had a list that was 300 items long, it'd download them with reusable cells and wouldn't download them ALL right at once. With this method am I not going to have to download every single picture to store in the array to use for my characterImages array? I can use cacheing and I think 300 is going to be a rare case, but isn't that going to be a big issue with data/  the app just getting overloaded when it does happen?

Comment: Instead of having the data array I guess I could perform the download in the getItemController with the index there yeah? I'll probably have a "Person" object and I can just do a download of the image for personArray[itemIndex].imageURL?

Comment: better to download image when user scroll this improves user interaction